# Change Input Value Stored in String using PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a form that allows a user to paste the code for an HTML form into a textarea. I then store the form they pasted in a string.

Before I echo that form back into my page template I want to change the value of the submit button.

Currently I am using jQuery to do this, but I would like to do it server side first.

Here is my jQuery Code:

```
    $("input[type='submit']").attr("value","my new value");
```

How would I search the string for that value using PHP and switch it out before the form is printed?

UPDATE: To clarify, I am trying to search a string for:

```
<input type="submit" value="old value" />
```

and replace it with

```
<input type="submit" value="new value" />
```

the string has a whole form inside it like this:

```
$string = '<form>
<input type="text" value="any">
<input type="submit" value="old value">
</form>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `DOMDocument`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($form);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$input = $xpath->query('//form/input[@type="submit"]')->item(0)->attributes;

foreach($input as $item){
    if($item->name == 'value'){
        $item->value = 'New Value';
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: That works perfect! Thanks for the detailed description it was very easy to follow.